# QT4 get base char without diacritics

Tags: c++, qt4, diacritics

I am trying to create an index from a list of QString, getting the first char for each word in the list. I would like to remove all diacritics from this first char, fe: á -> a, ü -> u, 木 -> 木. I mean, the index for abeja, ala, árbol should be the same: 'a'.

EDIT:
I have found the `QString normalized ( NormalizationForm mode ) const` method:

```
QString s = "á";
QString sWithoutDiacritic = s.normalized(QString::NormalizationForm_D).at(0);
```

Maybe this will do the trick, I'll try later.

Comment: It's probably the right solution. Also consider `"Æ"` or `"Ĳ"`. Mind you, there may be people who are very surprised to see "Ĳmuiden" listed under I instead of Y.

Comment: Thanks! For your examples I think that should be better to use: QString::NormalizationForm_KD, isn't it?

Comment: That depends on your application and data set, I guess. I wouldn't use it for a multilingual book index function, for the reasons stated: "Ĳmuiden" belongs under the Y, not under the I.

Comment: But, how can I obtain the Y from "IJmuiden"?

Comment: As the first answer notes, you generally don't need to. With the appropriate collation function, "IJ" collates with "Y".

Answer (score 0):

Collation (sorting order according to natural language) might be what you're looking for

The ICU Library provides such:

http://userguide.icu-project.org/collation/api